# как получить все комментарии со стены vk api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

цель: получить комментарии с записи на стене или сообществе

1. не понимаю где брать post_id
2. не понимаю как взять комментарии со стены человека
   формучане, помогите пожалуйста(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Обратимся к официальной документации к *API VK*.
   Согласно ей мы можем использовать метод **wall.get**, который в свою очередь возвращает объект, содержащий число результатов в поле count и **массив объектов записей на стене** в поле items. Сам массив объектов записей на стене включает в себя нужный вам *идентификатор записи.* (Подробнее: https://vk.com/dev/wall.get , https://vk.com/dev/objects/post)
2. Для получения комментариев со стены человека мы можем использовать метод **wall.getComments**, который также описан в документации к API. При использовании метода мы получаем информацию о комментариях к посту на стене. (Подробнее: https://vk.com/dev/wall.getComments)

Comment: тогда ещё один вопрос, мне нужно считать комментарии с закреплённого поста на странице или в группе, как это сделать?

Comment: @ЕгорКолесников метод wall.getComments после успешного выполнения возвращает объект, содержащий число результатов в поле count.

Comment: а как определить закреплённое сообщение?